# Navigation Bar isn't bound to the top swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I made an nav bar above my chat but now when I scroll the chatt you can see it at the status bar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Iyt.jpg

This is when I scroll all the way to the top but when I scroll down I get problems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJTde.jpg

The code I added above is just to show a comment so he can help me further.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want a view controller to go behind any bars, use this:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Comment: Hey, I added that but it still doesn't work. I am looking so the nav bar just fills in the top so the messages don't appear above it but just go under it understand?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to configure the navigation item in your view controller (so you don't create the navigation bar yourself, you leave that up to the containing `UINavigationController`). The following, I think, gets you fairly close.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Chat"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .close, target: nil, action: nil)
        // Color the backgrounds for debugging.
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

If you are using a storyboard to create your initial view controller then selecting your view controller and choosing the Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. Or if you are doing everything in code you just need to change wherever your create this current view controller to be something like:

```
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ChatViewController())
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work as well if the `prefersLargeTitles` on iOS 13. I'll edit this answer with a solution for that when I come up with it. However, your screenshot does not look like it has this option set to true, even though it is in your code, so maybe this is not a big deal.

Comment: Ok thanks! How would I now add the bar in the view? With what line of code?

Comment: It only shows when your view controller is contained within a UINavigationController.   You don't add the bar explicitly. So you need to either update the main storyboard or edit the code where your existing view controller is created so that it is contained in a UINavigationController.

Comment: The problem is that my viewcontroller an JSQMessagesViewController is so I can't do the last thing

Comment: Sure you can, you just embed the `JSQMessagesViewController` in a navigation controller. All the example images of that view controller appear to do exactly that. (I'm cloning the repo now to check)

Comment: Maybe update your question showing the code where you create the `JSQMessagesViewController`

Comment: OK, but the change needs to be made wherever you create your `ChatViewController`... From the code looks like it is created in a storyboard.

Comment: Yes, the ChatViewController is used by a view in the storyboard

Comment: So you need to embed the view controller of that scene into a navigation controller.

Comment: Ah I don't really now know how I would do that

Comment: Open the storyboard, find the ChatViewController, select it, go to the Editor menu, choose Embed In and from that submenu choose Navigation Controller.

Comment: Here's an animation http://xcodetips.com/tips/embed-in-navigation-controller.html

Comment: Hey, sick! It works now. the only problem is that the closebutton doesn't work anymore

Comment: @JonahBrandwagt Don't forget to mark the question as answered!